# How to track limited amounts of gifts with options

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I am creating an AccessDB for a small organization where members can receive 5 gifts each (gift certificate, magazine subscription, etc.) Within the gift there are options (gift certificate to Store A or Store B or Store C).  Same with subscription (Magazine A or Magazine B etc.).  Other gifts are without choice--ex: Member Keychain.

I need to track 'date received' and 'gift' --and 'gift choice' where applicable, making sure that each member receives one of each gift.

I am having trouble figuring out how/where to store this info--should it be in the members table, in a separate 1:1 table, or an entirely different way?

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please show us as much as you can do in detail so far, including different designs.